# Given n functions yi(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x2 + a3x3 and q queries

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, numpy, mathematical-optimization

Given n functions yi(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x2 + a3x3 and q queries.For each query, we are given an integer t and we are required to find out yi that minimizes yi(t).

supoose we have a list of list which contains the values of a0,a1,a2 and a3 for n functions [[10, 5, 4, 8],[2, 0 ,5, 0],[1, 8, 0, 2],[8, 7, 8, 7],[7, 0, 8, 1]]  and for different value of t we have to find the function that is minimum for that value of t.for example t=1 the function [2,0,5,0] would be minimum .I tried a brute force approach but for large value of n and large values of different t the script is too slow to execute.

```
lis= [[10, 5, 4, 8],[2, 0 ,5, 0],[1, 8, 0, 2],[8, 7, 8, 7],[7, 0, 8, 1]]
t=[1,3,5,7,9]
size=len(lis)
for j in t:
    matrix=[]
    for i in range(size):
        matrix.append(lis[i][0] + j*((lis[i][1]) + j*((lis[i][2]) + (lis[i][3]*j))))

    print(min(matrix))
```

output: `7 47 127 247 407`

Comment: What do you mean fails? Time is too big?

Comment: @UpmostScarab yes

Comment: First of all you have a mistake there. You should use different variables for cycles. Next I'd suggest you use `numpy.min` instead of `min` and `for j in lis` instead of `for j in range(size)`

Comment: @UpmostScarab Yeah it was a typing error.I just changed the variable name.

Comment: @UpmostScarab numpy.min won't make much of a difference  for large N and large length of t

Comment: I can't think of any solution right now, but one idea is that you can use multiprocessing to make things faster. Perhaps this could even be done using GPU.

Comment: This is a problem statement from an ongoing programming contest. This is an unhealthy practice. Request the community to refrain from answering it as it is done in an unethical fashion. Ref to question: https://www.codechef.com/NOV17/problems/POLY Thanks

Comment: Not a good practice, posting a ques from an ongoing programming contest. [link](https://www.codechef.com/NOV17/problems/POLY)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but maybe some thoughts that can speed things up.

It isn't entirely clear where that huge number of cubic polynomials comes from, but if they aren't entirely random, it might be possible to reduce the set.

For example, if I have a function f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d, and another function g(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + (d + e), with e>0, than the g(x) can be eliminated from the set because g(x) = f(x) + e, hence always greater than f(x).

Something alike can be done with the quadratic term. If you find a g(x) = f(x) + ex^2, with e > 0, g(x) can be eliminated because the quadratic term is greater or equal zero.

Since sorting the array of polynomials has a complexity of O(n log n), sorting doesn't hurt (we're dealing with a complexity of O(nm), with n = number of polynomials, m = number of input).
Scanning the array has a complexity of O(n) and doesn't hurt either.

Polynomials with large positive coefficients in front of the cube will be promising candidates for large negative input, and vice versa.
As long as the polynomials are similar, this idea might be exploitable to cut the search.